# What is the most convincing command in Vim

Tags: vim, editor

I want to ditch my current editor. I feel I need something else. That do not expose my hands to the risk of RSI. I need to see why I should change editor. And it would be nice to believe, that I will be coding when I'm 80 years old.

All the big guys out there are using Vim. The only Emacs guy I know are RMS. Paul Graham is a Vi dude.

Comment: What editor are (were) you ditching?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`.` (dot) - repeats the last editing action. Really handy when you need to perform a few similar edits.

Answer (score 19):

:help usr_12.txt

That'll bring up a section in the help system that discusses "Clever Tricks".  If those don't get you excited I don't know what will!

Answer (score 18):

[Recording macros](http://julipedia.blogspot.com/2005/12/vim-macros.html)

Answer (score 16):

The asterisk.

```
*
```

Its effect: Immediately search for the next instance of the word under the cursor.

Comment: This VIM quick reference guide (nice and printable) was very handy for learning useful commands: http://tnerual.eriogerg.free.fr/vim.html

Comment: Also worth mentioning #, it does the same, except searchs backwards.

Answer (score 16):

The best thing is the efficiency with which you can edit code (which is done a lot in programming). The commands such as

- cw to change a word
- dw to delete a word
- ct, to change all text until the next comma
- ci( to change the contents of the parentheses you're currently in
- xp to correct spelling mistakes ("spleling" -> cursor on l -> xp -> "spelling")
- o to insert a new line below and start editing
- O to insert a new line above

Then there is the possibility to work with named registers very quickly. To move a block, just select it, press d, then move to it's new location and press p. Much faster than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>. Use "ud to delete text and move it to register u (I use this one for the commenting template).

And also Vim has all the scripting support you need (either using it's native scripting language or using Python, Ruby, ...)

Answer (score 7):

the numbers.

in command mode
type a number ( any number of digits )
type a command.

that command will be executed $number times

ie:

99dd

erases the next 99 lines.

Comment: or 78a/<ESC> to write 78 times the character '/' (useful for comment adornments)

Answer (score 3):

1. The fast startup time.
2. The sharp distinction between editing and viewing. (you know when you edit)
3. The only way you ever find what you are looking for is with search "/" and that is good, since it much faster than your eyes.

But the best command(s) are:

/  - search string

ZZ - quit

.  - repeat last insert (I think)

%! - insert unix command

Comment: The speed is real important to me. A lot of other editors are slow, especially with multiple big files open.

Answer (score 2):

Handling multi line regexps in search strings with "`\_.`". While checking over 4GB text files of various formats, it had saved my life several times.

Comment: but don't forget to turn *off* syntax highlighting before opening such a big file...

Comment: As these are mostly plain texts there is no syntax highlight for them. And using the largefile extension ( http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506 ) helps a bit too.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you looking to be convinced to start using a different editor? If you're happy with what you have now, stick. If not, perhaps ask about editors with features that you lack.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are using Visual Studio there is the wonderful vsvim.

Answer (score 0):

The lovely built in regular expression evaluator.

Answer (score 0):

I love the speed of Vim but I find it lacks the features of a modern IDE for C++ development. Eclipse CDT with the [viPlugin](http://satokar.com/viplugin/) is a good compromise.

You get the power and source overview provided by Eclipse CDT with the speed and flexibility of Vim for coding.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe reading "[Come home to vim](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/09/coming-home-to-vim/)" by Steve Losh article is a good start, or 
a [series of videos](http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/vim-essential-plugins/) about interesting plugins. And be sure to see some articles on the site [vimcasts.org](http://vimcasts.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You should map Caps Lock to Esc. It will make getting out of insert mode feel natural as opposed to the awkward move you must make to press the ESC key. Besides, who uses Caps Lock anyway?

Answer (score -1):

```
\v
```

Make your regular expressions mostly Perl compatible.

See very magic section [here](http://briancarper.net/blog/448/vim-regexes-are-awesome) for more information.

Answer (score -2):

To be truly inspired, you must see a vim guru in action.  If you do not have a local guru, here is a video to inspire you.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jDWBJOXs_iI&feature=related

If you don't already know vim, the speed at which code is navigated, sliced, and diced will be indistinguishable from magic.  After a few months of studying vim, the same editing speed will seem commonplace.